# Website shows a blank page when opened from search engines or href links, but works with url directly typed

Tags: nginx, website

I met a strange problem, www.vimooc.org, this is the site.

It will be a blank page if go through the search engine or a href link, but it will work fine if the complete url is typed on the address bar of the browser.

Why???

Update:

I located the problem, however still don't know how to solve it.

It is the referer problem.

As long as there is a `Referer: xxxx` in the header, the http request gets no response.

The header that is not working:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.vimooc.org
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.17 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Referer: http://vfxware.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9
Cookie: showEdit=true; sessionid=xxxx; ONLINE_NUMBER=xxxx
```

The header which is working:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.vimooc.org
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.17 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9
Cookie: showEdit=true;  sessionid=xxxx; ONLINE_NUMBER=xxxx
```

And this is my nginx conf:

```
upstream inxedu_web {
    session_sticky mode=insert option=indirect;
    server 127.0.0.1:1011;

    check interval=3000 rise=2 fall=2 timeout=1000 type=http;
    check_http_send "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
    check_http_expect_alive http_2xx http_3xx;
}

server {
    listen  443 ssl;

    server_name www.vimooc.org ;
    ssl_certificate /home/tom/yinkuSSLCert/www/full_chain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/tom/yinkuSSLCert/www/private.key;

        location /socket.io/{
                proxy_pass http://socket_nodes;
        }

        location ~* \.(html|htm|shtml|zip|rar|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|ppts|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|ico|js|css)$ {
                root /data/htdocs/inxedu_web;
        }

        location /  {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
                proxy_redirect  off;
                session_sticky_hide_cookie upstream=inxedu_web;
                proxy_pass http://inxedu_web;
        }
        access_log off;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

- Your server is configured to block access when the HTTP [`Referer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) header is present in a request. Maybe an overzealous attempt to forbid resource hotlinking.
- Your webapp crashes when it tries to interpret the `Referer` header from requests.

Comment: I think it's the first reason, then how to correct the setting?

Comment: I added `proxy_set_header Referer "";` it then works, but is it the right way to do it ?